# Apply grad-cam to u-net model (InvalidArgumentError: {{function_node __wrapped__Pack_N_2_device_)

Tags: python, heatmap, gradient, unet-neural-network

[I use the u-net model with activation as sigmoid](https://i.stack.imgur.com/WC625.png)

[when I calculate the gradient of the top prediction layer for our input image . I get error .I can't calculate the document. I tried many ways but still can't fix it please help me](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Y2hfw.png)

Comment: Please post the code as a text, and not a screenshot.